# What is the default value for IMultiConverter?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net-4.5

### Background...

I have this code that crashes the entire application once every 4 months.

The crash is in the `ConvertBack` function (according to the stack trace):

```
public enum MultiBoolConverterType
{
    And,
    Or,
}

public class MultiBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public MultiBoolConverterType ConverterType { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var booleans = values.OfType<bool>();

        switch (ConverterType)
        {
            case MultiBoolConverterType.And:

                return booleans.All(b => b);

            case MultiBoolConverterType.Or:

                return booleans.Any(b => b);

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

### Question

What do I replace `throw new NotImplementedException();` with to ensure that if `ConvertBack` is inadvertently called, it does no harm?

Comment: Whatever you want to return.

Comment: So if I return null, will it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Binding.DoNothing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you return if you actually have no value.

In `ConvertBack` you should throw `NotSupportedException`, because there is no inverse function for this converter. You will have to make sure that this is never called yourself, via `BindingMode=OneWay` and the like.

Comment: I tried returning Binding.DoNothing, but it got a compile error because it could not cast to `object[]`.

Comment: Well, you are not supposed to use that here anyway, otherwise you could return an array of `DoNothings`.

Comment: That's a hack, why do you insist on that?

Comment: For safety. I work in a large project with many developers. If another developer uses this converter, and forgets to set it to OneWay, then the entire application will crash, and heads will roll.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from `H.B.`, return an array of `Binding.DoNothing`:

```
public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    _log.Warn("Warning. Reverse binding on MultiBoolConverter called. Prevent this by using OneWay.");

    List<object> result = new List<object>();
    foreach(var t in targetTypes)
    {
        result.Add(Binding.DoNothing);
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```